# Importing Static library into Custom Universal framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, frameworks, static-libraries

I have created a custom universal framework by following this tutorial
[tutorial](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/).

Here My question is how to import a static library .a files into framework.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the .a file into your frameworks folder.

Or you can go to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Click on the '+' sign -> Add Other (bottom left) -> choose your .a and click Add

[image]

Make sure to include the header files of your static library in your new project as well.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. am not quite getting your ans adding .a file to project file or framework source project ??. Where to import static library's headers ??

Comment: Are you planning to use this library on another Xcode project?

Comment: Okay, then which part of my answer do you not understand? As for the header files, just create a new folder, and copy and paste just the header files into it. Then drag and drop that header file into your new project

Comment: Hey dude i think you wrongly understood the question. I have found the answer please check it below

Answer (score 0):

In my custom framework project setup I have added the static library which I have created to link binary with libraries and I have added the static library header files to Aggregate target copy files build phase. thats it builded like charm. and that framework is working fine.